# Syntax error checking whether account number is numeric

Tags: shell

```
if [[ ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ &&  ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

This is intended to check whether the account number is numeric or not. I'm getting a syntax error.

*An earlier version of this question lacked the space between `if` and `[[`; the actual code has the required space.*

It showing the below error message:

```
syntax error: `${account_nr}' missing expression operator
```

I am using bash shell. You people are telling it is working. but I am trying with example like below it is giving error.

```
jai = "CNM"
hanuman = "BRK"
if [[ $jai =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $hanuman =~ ^[0-9]+$  ]]
then
  echo "Jai hanuman"
  echo "valid input"
fi
```

it showing the error like below.

```
./temp.sh: line 11: jai: command not found
./temp.sh: line 12: hanuman: command not found
```

In my actual program it is not working:
" Now I am givig the problem indetail:"

1. In one file I stored all the transactions details, each line for one transaction.
2. by using the below while loop each time I am reading one transaction detail
   while read  blank srvrtid blank member_nr blank account_nr blank acct_type blank routing_nr blank amount blank proc_date blank from_account_nr blank from_acct_type blank
   do
3. Inside this I want to check account_nr and  from_account_nr values are numeric or not
   the if condition I have given the below

   `if [[ ${SQL_STATEMENT} -gt 0 && ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ && ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]`
4. It is not showing any error for `&{SQL_STATEMENT}`, this `SQL_STATEMENT` is assigned with the value returned by the SELECT query.(total number of transactions).
5. when I run the script it is showing the below error.

   syntax error: `${account_nr}' missing expression operator.

please help for my problem.

Comment: So this line causes syntax error? `if [[ ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ &&  ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]`

Comment: What shell are you using? I ran your updated `if` in `bash` and it worked fine, as-is. It would help if you shared your error message. In expressing a problem like this, these bit of detail matter quite a lot.

Comment: @mbratch He made an edit 9 minutes after you answered. I think he just doesn't want to admit the mistake or accept an answer.

Comment: You will not get a useful answer to this question unless you provide more information, as requested. Tell us what shell you're using, and show the exact error message in your question. (Posting [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18805351/827263) again is particularly unhelpful.) I've edited your question in an attempt to make it somewhat clearer; please confirm that this is still what you want to ask.

Comment: It would help if you would state the actual problem. You've changed it a couple of times now. I just updated my answer which fixes a syntax error in your latest version.

Comment: What line of your script is it reporting the syntax error on? If I use the `if` statement you show, I do not get a syntax error. Are you sure `account_nr` is being assigned a value before the `if`?

Comment: Mbratch thaks for replying.

Comment: The thing is account_nr has the value. without any value assigned to that variable also it needs to work, because we used "blank" before that one when reading. It is showing the error in that if statement only.

Comment: @jcrshankar, yes your `if` actually should work with a blank `account_nr`.You still have not indicated which line in your script is giving the error. Also, please show lines before and after the `if`. Finally, please try this and tell me what happens, enter at the command prompt: `if [[ ${SQL_STATEMENT} -gt 0 && ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ && ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo foo; fi` and tell me what happens.

Comment: If we read the values from the file through the "while" loop at that time it not working. It is giving error in this "if" statement only. The error is Syntax error: `${account_nr}' missing expression operator.

Comment: I want to know what happens if you enter the `if` I gave you at the bash prompt. Not in your `while` loop or script file. And without more context, it will be difficult to explain why it gives an error in your `while` loop. It must depend upon something else in the script that you aren't showing.

Answer (score 3):

A space is required between `if` and `[`:

```
$ account_num=1234
$ if [[ ${accoun_num} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then echo "foo" ; fi
foo
$
```

Also, this works fine in `bash`:

```
$ account_nr=1234
$ from_account_nr=9876
$ if [[ ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ && ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then echo "foo" ; fi
foo
$
```

You cannot have spaces around your shell variable assignments, either. Below is a correction to your latest version:

```
jai="CNM"
hanuman="BRK"
if [[ $jai =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $hanuman =~ ^[0-9]+$  ]]
then
  echo "Jai hanuman"
  echo "valid input"
fi
```

Since neither `jai` or `hanuman` are numbers, the above script runs and outputs nothing. If you set them both to a number, then it will display:

```
Jai hanuman
valid input
```

Note that if you put a space, like so:

```
jai = "CNM"
```

Then the shell (`bash`) thinks you are executing a command called `jai` and you get the error indicated.

Answer (score 0):

This line is correct with advanced shells like Bash, Zsh or Ksh.

```
if [[ ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ &&  ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

It won't work with POSIX shells but -still- it won't show syntax error. Instead it would show that the command `[[` was not found. Other causes may be related to the `if` statement itself but you have to show us what message was exactly shown e.g. `` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' ``