# I am getting syntax error while using the if condition in the below manner

Tags: shell

```
if [[ ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ && ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

In the above I am getting the values for `account_nr`, `from_account_nr`  from a file.  I need to check  account_nr  and from_account_nr  both are numeric or not. but here I am getting Syntax error.

Please help me

Comment: What was the complete syntax error message shown?

Comment: You already posted this question. Why are you posting it again?

Comment: This problem was already posted and being covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805124/syntax-error-checking-whether-account-number-is-numeric

Comment: Please show your whole script and indicate what the error message is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

All fine here:

```
if [[ ${account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ && ${from_account_nr} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo a ; else echo b ; fi
b
```